# How do you parse json response in Netlogo

Tags: json, rest, netlogo

Im trying to connect from NetLogo to Knime(Machine Learning Platform) that provides prediction probabilities for the turtle variables that are passed via a REST from NetLogo. So communication is two way, 1) send turtle variables from NetLogo to Knime and 2)receive Probability from Knime to NetLogo. Intention is to perform this activity for each turtle. Im currently doing this via separate csv files, one for turtle variables and other for rules and probabilities.

Im using make-request from web extension to a test side and received response. However, im unable to parse the response in NetLogo to get only the element im interested in.

In parallel im also testing with python extension.

```
to setup
  
  let url "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1" 
  let method "GET"
  let jsonResponse web:make-request url "GET" [] []
  print jsonResponse
end
```

response: **(I want to read title from the response below)**

[{
"userId": 1,
"id": 1,
"title": "delectus aut autem",
"completed": false
} HTTP/1.1 200 OK]